# Dynamic generation of options in select box

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular6

I am having two select boxes with values as,

**Select Box 1 TS**

```
  projects = [
    {
      key: 1, value: "Project one",
    },
    {
      key: 2, value: "Project two",
    },
    {
      key: 3, value: "Project three",
    }
  ]
```

**HTML for above,**

```
<select name="project" (change)="changeProject($event)">
<option *ngFor="let opt of projects" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>
</select>
```

**Select Box 2 TS**

```
  propertyCode = [
    {
      key: 101, value: "PC101",
    },
    {
      key: 102, value: "PC102",
    },
    {
      key: 103, value: "PC103",
    }
  ]
```

**HTML for above,**

```
<select name="project" (change)="changePropertyCode($event)">
<option *ngFor="let opt of propertyCode" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>
</select>
```

Here upon selecting any option from dropdown one and dropdown two, i need to generate a new set of options for dropdown three..

For eg,

**Scenario 1**

If i have choosen `Project Two` and `PC103` both select boxes respectively, then i need to have the dropdown as,

```
  product = [
    {
      key: 123, value: "PC103PROD123",
    },
    {
      key: 456, value: "PC103PROD456",
    },
    {
      key: 789, value: "PC103PROD789",
    }
  ]
```

**Scenario 2**

If i have choosen `Project Three` and `PC102` both select boxes respectively, then i need to have the dropdown as,

```
  product = [
    {
      key: 123, value: "PC102PROD123",
    },
    {
      key: 456, value: "PC102PROD456",
    },
    {
      key: 789, value: "PC102PROD789",
    }
  ]
```

Here you can see the value has initial characters as `PC103` and `PC102` respectively which is going to change upon selection of two option from first two select box respectively.

I need to generate the option as like above if i choose the mentioned selection from those selectboxes.

**Working stackblitz** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjhsun

Kindly help me to generate the third select box options dynamically based on selection of first and second select box option **using pure angular, typescript or javascript without jquery**..

Comment: YOu don't have data for third dropdown. Can you add it in your stackblitz?

Comment: @Jai, That is what my requirement, i need to generate it in dynamic based on the selection of first two..   ```<option *ngFor="let opt of product" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>``` is given in stackblitz and that ```product``` array only going to change upon selection of first two dropdown values.

Comment: That means you want to create options based on the other dropdowns. The question is how many? Because at one time there will be just one selection for both dropdowns. Based on what you need morethan 1 option for 3rd dropdown.

Comment: KIndly read after the line ```For eg,``` in my question.., If i choose ```Project Two and PC103```, then my third (product) dropdown going to be as like expected above, if i change that then the product dropdown needs to be change accordingly.. (Summarized two scenario in my question how the product needs to change upon selection)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a private method that would set the `products` array based on the `selectedProject` and `seletedProperty` properties:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {

  selectedProject;
  selectedProperty;
  product;

  projects = [
    {
      key: 1, value: "Project one",
    },
    {
      key: 2, value: "Project two",
    },
    {
      key: 3, value: "Project three",
    }
  ]

  propertyCode = [
    {
      key: 101, value: "PC101",
    },
    {
      key: 102, value: "PC102",
    },
    {
      key: 103, value: "PC103",
    }
  ]

  changeProject() {
    this.setProducts();
  }

  changePropertyCode() {
    this.setProducts();
  }

  private setProducts() {
    if ((this.selectedProject === "Project two" && this.selectedProperty === 'PC103') || (this.selectedProject === "Project three" && this.selectedProperty === 'PC102')) {

      let potentialProduct = [
        {
          key: 123, value: `${this.selectedProperty}PROD123`,
        },
        {
          key: 456, value: `${this.selectedProperty}PROD456`,
        },
        {
          key: 789, value: `${this.selectedProperty}PROD789`,
        }
      ]

      this.product = potentialProduct;
    } else {
      this.product = [];
    }
  }

}
```

And then in your template, use the `[(ngModel)]` for `projects` and `properties` dropdowns:

```
<select 
  name="project" 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedProject" 
  (change)="changeProject($event)">
  <option 
    *ngFor="let opt of projects" 
    [value]="opt.value">
    {{opt.value}}
  </option>
</select>
<br><br>

<select 
  name="project" 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedProperty" 
  (change)="changePropertyCode($event)">
  <option 
    *ngFor="let opt of propertyCode" 
    [value]="opt.value">
    {{opt.value}}
  </option>
</select>
<br><br>

<select 
  name="project" 
  (change)="changeProductCode($event)">
  <option 
    *ngFor="let opt of product" 
    [value]="opt.key">
    {{opt.value}}
  </option>
</select>
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-dropdown-third-select-value-set?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: @undefined, just added. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hmte3w) is a link to stackblitz. This might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

It Seems from your above requirement that you only need the display string of select option to be dynamic and the actual values of  tag in the third drop down are fixed.

If the above case is true, then you can do as below

Your array of key value object will be like below only

```
product = [
  {
    key: 123, value: "PROD123",
  },
  {
    key: 456, value: "PROD456",
  },
  {
    key: 789, value: "PROD789",
  }
]
```

And you just have to append the selected string [Which will be binded with one variable already]

```
<select name="project" [(ngModel)]='productString' 
    (ngModelChange)='onOptionsSelected($event)'>
        <option *ngFor="let opt of product" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>
 </select>
```

And your TS code for `onOptionsSelected(event)` method will be

```
onOptionsSelected(event){
    console.log(event)
    for(let item of this.product){
      if(item.key==event){
        this.productStringValue=item.value
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

See Below stackblitz live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrk9b3